# why does this code won't display hello world? It says text.content of null

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code by linking this code to html using script but display

> uncaught error: text.content of null.

```
const myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
myHeading.textContent = 'Hello world!';
```

Comment: Probably you just don't have an h1 tag in your HTML...

Comment: seems the `document.querySelector('h1');` returned null instead of the expected value